# How to exclude holidays dates in Angular/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

I have not been able to find solution to this. Please,  I wrote this code for calculating differences between business hours for a leave duration, I also took note of the lunch time and weekends. However, i want to extend it to accommodate holidays. For example, if the dates in the array ['2020-07-15', '2020-07-16', 2020-07-17'] are holidays. Please, how can i exclude these holiday days based on the dates passed in the array. Thanks

```
onChangeDate(){
var minutesWorked = 0;
var startDate = new Date(this.leaveList.date_from);
var endDate = new Date(this.leaveList.date_to);
var holidays = [ new Date (2020, 6, 27), new Date(2020, 6, 28 )]
if(endDate < startDate){
    return 0;
}
var current  = startDate
// Define work range
var workHoursStart = 8.30;
var workHoursEnd = 18;
var excludeWeekends = true;
var excludeLunch = true;
// Loop while currentDate is less than end Date (by minutes)
while(current <= endDate){   
       
    if(current.getHours() >= workHoursStart && current.getHours() < workHoursEnd && (excludeWeekends ? current.getDay() !== 0 && current.getDay() !== 6 : true)
    &&(excludeLunch ? current.getHours() !== 12 && current.getHours() !==13.30: true)){
        
          minutesWorked++;
    }
    current.setTime(current.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
}
this.leaveList.hours = Math.floor(minutesWorked / 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try another approach that will not only save no of iterations but also gives an effective solution.

1. Find no of hours per day ( conditioning the lunch hours)
2. Find no of days ( conditioning the weekend days)

```js
function onChangeDate(){
  var minutesWorked = 0;
  var startDate = new Date(this.leaveList.date_from);
  var endDate = new Date(this.leaveList.date_to);
  var holidays = [ new Date (2020, 6, 27), new Date(2020, 6, 28 )];
  holidays = holidays.map(function(holidayDate){
    return holidayDate.toDateString();
  })
  if(endDate < startDate){
    return 0;
  }
  var current  = startDate
  // Define work range
  var workHoursStart = 8.5;
  var workHoursEnd = 18;
  var excludeWeekends = true;
  var excludeLunch = true;
  var lunchTime = 1.5; // define just the no of hours of lunch
  var hoursPerDay = workHoursEnd - workHoursStart;
  if(excludeLunch){
    hoursPerDay = hoursPerDay - lunchTime;
  }
  var noOfDays = 0;
  while(current <= endDate){
    var currentDateValue = current.toDateString();
    var currentDay = current.getDay();
    if((!excludeWeekends || (excludeWeekends && currentDay < 6 && currentDay > 0))
       && holidays.indexOf(currentDateValue) == -1){
      noOfDays++;
    }
    current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
  }
  
  var hours = hoursPerDay*noOfDays;
  this.leaveList.hours = hours;

}
```